# Radiobuttons as a group in different panels

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

I'm using `C#` to develop `WindowsForms` application. I have created a form with some panels. Each panel has a `RadioButton`. When I click a `RadioButton`, and then other one, both are checked.

How could I simulate that all the `RadioButtons` are in the same group, so only one can be checked, and the others are unchecked?

Of course, I can control the checkedChanged event for each `RadioButton` ... but is there any better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadioButtons are automatically linked if they are inside the same parent. Since you want them to live in different containers you will have to link them manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In Java workd, I saw a RadioGroup class that links, and I was guessing if there was a similar class in C#. I'll write the logic using the CheckedChanged event. Thanks!